# Why can't I add a simple image to my HomePage (Stless widget)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just experimenting with Flutter for the past couple of days. I am trying to add an image but it won't show up at all.
Am I missing something obvious?

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'PicHuntingNigga',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('PicHunting-Nigga'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new MyCameraWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCameraWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var assetImage = new AssetImage('assets/images/camera1.png');
    var image = new Image(image: assetImage, width: 225.0, height: 225.0);
    return new Container(child: image);
  }
}
```

**and my pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter



flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/images/camera.png
  - assets/images/camera1.png
  - assets/images/
```

**My folder structure**

[image]

After I run the emulator - everything shows up minus the picture.I can replace the image with child: `Text('asdasdasda')`, and it will render the text but not the image.

Comment: FYI. You don't need to reference every image, you can just name the folder and flutter will be able to find all the assets inside. `- assets/images/`

Comment: I would edit the titles you have put in the code above in your materialapp and appbar, it might break a stackoverflow rule.....

Comment: excellent point...I need better naming convention even when just messing around with code.

Comment: I tested your code with a random image and it worked without a problem for me. Try to type "flutter clean" in the terminal and re-run your project, if you're lucky maybe that will fix your problem.

Comment: mhmhmh that's good toknow! it shows images when I get it from an API but for some reason, it wont render if it's on the assets folder :/

Answer (score 0):

Also see this example here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
  return DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('images/background.png'),
        // ...
      ),
      // ...
    ),
  );
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It is on the root folder, no?

Comment: Just spotted that, my mistake, check update. The issue is it's not wrapped in DecoratedBox

Comment: Nope - it still won't render the image :/ I'll keep trying. Not sure why I am having such a hard time with such an easy thing.

Comment: Nope - I am setting up a new emulator device. There are no errors so I almost feel like it's an issue with the emulator or the image (I've tried a couple of images)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it!

Not sure how....I just turned off my laptop and then turned it on. I also had dinner and now it's working.

So if you're stuck with a similar issue - have dinner? that seemed to have been the solution for me.